# simple array into associative array, based on 'directory tree' like values of the first one

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

For example, I have array

```
Array
(
    [0] => folder1/file1.txt
    [1] => folder1/file2.txt
    [2] => file2.txt
    [3] => folder2/file1.txt
    [4] => folder1/subfolder1/file1.txt
    [5] => folder1/subfolder2/file2.txt
    [6] => file1.txt
    [7] => file3.txt
    [8] => folder1/subfolder2/file1.txt
)
```

I need a clue to figure how to create 'directory tree' array, based on the given values, that it could look like this:

```
Array
(
    [folder1] => Array
        (
            [0] => file1.txt
            [1] => file2.txt
            [subfolder1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => file1.txt
                )

            [subfolder2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => file1.txt
                    [1] => file2.txt
                )

        )

    [0] => file1.txt
    [1] => file2.txt
    [2] => file3.txt
)
```

Now second array is a tree of the first array (made manually).  =)

And I can't figure how to achieve this automatically.

Comment: Possible dupe of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479543/php-how-to-populate-a-directory-structure-in-an-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8479543/php-how-to-populate-a-directory-structure-in-an-array)?

Comment: @Kristen Jukowski that topic involves real files and dirs, and I don't have ones

Comment: @KristenJukowski That question starts with a recursive directory iterator, this question starts with a flat array. I'm pretty sure I answered a similar question a while back, I'm trying to find it.

Comment: @Barmar I've searched for it too. unsuccessfully

Comment: Something like [this](https://eval.in/51998)? But that kind of structure calls for trouble: what if you have folder named `0` ?

Comment: @EL Sorry dude! I should brush up on my reading comprehension skills...

Comment: @Glavić looks great, but folder names realyy can happen to be nums. And also I can't get how your code is working =)) Anyway, put it as answer, and I'll accept it

Comment: @Glavić Post it as an answer. I agree with your comment about the structure.

Comment: Instead of having indexed entries for files, have them also be associative entries, but the value could be something like `true` to indicate that it's a file rather than a subdirectory, e.g. `"file.txt" => true`

Comment: @Barmar: folders can also be named as `file.txt`. Workaround would be to name indexes as folder or file, like you said, but with addition, to prepend slash at foldername, [like this example](https://eval.in/52001).

Comment: @Glavić You can't have both a file and folder with the same name, so that's not a problem. Either the value is `true` if it's a file, or the value is an array if it's a directory.

Comment: @Barmar: I know, but since OP said this structure is not real files and dirs, you never know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples example ([demo](https://eval.in/51998)), that will generate output like you wish, but you will get conflict if you will have same folder and file name in the same directory level ([demo](https://eval.in/52000)).

```
$files = [
    'folder1/file1.txt',
    'folder1/file2.txt',
    'file2.txt',
    'folder2/file1.txt',
    'folder1/subfolder1/file1.txt',
    'folder1/subfolder2/file2.txt',
    'file1.txt',
    'file3.txt',
    'folder1/subfolder2/file1.txt',
];

$tree = [];
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $a = explode('/', $file);
    $array = &$tree;
    foreach (array_slice($a, 0, -1) as $folder) {
        if (!isset($array[$folder])) $array[$folder] = [];
        $array = &$array[$folder];
    }
    $array[] = end($a);
}
print_r($tree);
```

To overcome problem with same folder and file named on the same level you can create folder indexes with slash at the end, like `folder/`, so there cannot be any conflict ([demo](https://eval.in/52001)).

Comment: `you can create folder indexes` do you mean empty folders?

Comment: No, I meant that if you have a folder, array index will be with slash as `folder/`. And empty folders are also supported. [Example](https://eval.in/52021).