# PHP function to read directory & collect filenames &subdirectory names into an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have been trying to find the correct PHP function to do the following:

**PHP function that reads a directory and collects all the filenames (and subdirectory names) into an array.**

I have been searching for a while, not to sure on what exactly is the correct answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: check [php directory iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php)

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan Here is even better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014474/php-read-sub-directories-and-loop-through-files-how-to

Comment: I had similar question, but it depends whicj result (array structure) do you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141998/simple-array-into-associative-array-based-on-directory-tree-like-values-of-th

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php - to open directory

Links to read directory.

Would imagine there is an example

Answer (score -1):

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826963/php-list-all-files-in-directory)

```
<?php 
function dirToArray($dir) { 

   $result = array(); 

   $cdir = scandir($dir); 
   foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) 
   { 
      if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) 
      { 
         if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)) 
         { 
            $result[$value] = dirToArray($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value); 
         } 
         else 
         { 
            $result[] = $value; 
         } 
      } 
   } 

   return $result; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: I just need the name to the function, not the actual code implementing it.