# PHP classes cannot be loaded unless namescape is included or commented out

Tags: php, autoloader, psr-0

After searching through the site, I'm at a loss as to why I'm getting a fatal error about my class not being found unless I either instantiate the class with the namescape prefixing it, or comment out the namescape in the class file. I'm using PSR-0 to try and resolve this issue with no luck, along with [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752256/php-classes-with-a-namespace-cannot-be-loaded-via-spl-autoload-register), which was the closest to my issue.

Autoloader code:

```
    function autoload($className)
{
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName;
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

Path for all three files (Autoloader.php, Class.php, index.php) are all on the same directory level. No subdirectories or anything like that.

Autoloader code is implemented at the beginning of index.php with a require_once("Autoloader.php");

Classes are called at $foo = new classFoo();

tl;dr version:

- Commenting out namescape declaration in class being called? Works
  fine.
- Instantiating class using namescape/class formatting? Works
  fine.
- Otherwise? Fatal error: Class not found (even though it's in
  the same directory.

Comment: Provide more info: How your classes are declared, what are the full filesystem paths to them, how autoloader is implemented, etc etc

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for the reply. I've updated the question with the data that you requested.

Comment: And how classes are declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the global namespace, and the classes are in some other namespace, then even if the files are `require`d by autoloader or manually, you still need to use the namespace when declaring the class.  That is the point of namespacing, to prevent class name collisions.

It looks like you may be mixing [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) since you have namespaced classes but they aren't pathed properly `\<NamespaceName>(\<SubNamespaceNames>)*\<ClassName>`.

Comment: So the correct path would be say rootDirectory\foo for namescape \foo? That would explain one issue for sure (everything's on the same directory level)

Comment: Correct, since the autoloader is in the root directory and it is loading relative to the root directory.  So if you had `namespace foo; class Test {}` then the file path would be `root/foo/Test.php`

Comment: And the declaration for a new class would have to be new foo/Test(); as well?

Comment: Yes it would need to be `new Foo\Test();` which the autoloader will then resolve to `foo/Test.php`.  Or you can have `use foo\Test;` and then you just need to do `new Test()`, but it will still resolve to `foo/Test.php`