# Directory Iterator To Custom Array

Tags: php, json, directory, iteration, jstree

Im trying to produce this for JSTree

```
[
            {"id":2,"text":"Child node 1"},
            {"id":3,"text":"Child node 2"},
            {
                "text" : "Root node",
                "state" : { "opened" : true },
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "text" : "Child node 1",
                        "state" : { "selected" : true },
                        "icon" : "jstree-file"
                    },
                    { "text" : "Child node 222", "state" : { "disabled" : true } }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Im trying to create this via using DirectoryIterator

I got the following off of the php website

```
   $ritit = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory), FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS); 
    $r = array(); 
    foreach ($ritit as $splFileInfo) { 


        $path = $splFileInfo->isDir() 
         ? array($splFileInfo->getFilename() => array()) 
         : array($splFileInfo->getFilename()); 

       for ($depth = $ritit->getDepth() - 1; $depth >= 0; $depth--) { 
       $path = array($ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->current()->getFilename() => $path); 
       } 

       $r = array_merge_recursive($r, $path); 

    }
```

This outputs

Array
(
    [.] => Array
    (
    )

```
[..] => Array
(
)

[0] => Christmas.docx
[test1] => Array
    (
    )

[test2] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

I tried modifying it to this

```
$k = array(); 
foreach ($ritit as $splFileInfo) { 
    //skip if its '.' or '..'
    if ($splFileInfo->getFilename() === '.' || $splFileInfo->getFilename() === '..') {
    continue;
    }

    //if is dir
   if($splFileInfo->isDir()) {

        $path[] = array("text" => $splFileInfo->getFilename(), "children" => array()) ;

        } else {
             $path[] = array("text" => $splFileInfo->getFilename());

    }        

   for ($depth = $ritit->getDepth() - 1; $depth >= 0; $depth--) { 
   $path["children"] = array($ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->current()->getFilename() => $path); 
   } 

   $k = array_merge_recursive($k, $path); 

}
```

And this outputs

```
Array
(
    [test2] => Array
        (
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [text] => Christmas.docx
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [text] => Christmas.docx
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [text] => test1
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [text] => Christmas.docx
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [text] => test1
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [text] => test2
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Please could you help me with what i'm meant to be doing to iterate through the file structure and return an array that i can convert into the json at the start of the post?

---

update

credit to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3556894/1842842

I've got this now :

```
function requestAccountFolderStructure($dir) {
    $list = array();
    $path = $dir;
    $i = 0;
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {
        if ($file->isDot())
            continue;

        if ($file->isDir()) {
            $record = array();
            $record['id'] =  $i;
            $record['text'] =  $file->getFilename();
            $record['children'] = array();            
            $record['path'] = $file->getPathInfo()->getFilename();            
            if (is_dir($dir . '/' . $file)) {
                $record['children'] = requestAccountFolderStructure($dir . '/' . $file);
            }
            $list[] = $record;
            $i++;
        }

    }
    return $list;
}

   $dir = 'folder/';
   $directories = requestAccountFolderStructure($dir);

   foreach($directories as $directory){
       //if(count($directory['children'] === 1)){
           $dir = new DirectoryIterator('folder/' . $directory['text']);
            foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if (!$fileinfo->isDir()) {
                    $directories[$directory['id']]['children'][] = array("text" => $fileinfo->getFilename(),"icon" => "jstree-file" );
        }
            }
       //}     
   }  

   print_r(json_encode($directories));
```

Which produces for me

```
[{"id":0,"text":"test1","children":[{"text":"1.docx","icon":"jstree-file"}],"path":"folder"},{"id":1,"text":"test2","children":[{"id":0,"text":"New folder","children":[],"path":"test2"},{"text":"2.txt","icon":"jstree-file"}],"path":"folder"}]
```

i just need to figure out making it iterative in the sub sub folders now

Comment: "i just need to figure out making it iterative in the sub sub folders now" - Read about recursion, that should do it.

Comment: Thanks :D got there in the end (added answer), and with code i understand!. I was having trouble (still dont understand it) with this line `$path = array($ritit->getSubIterator($depth)->current()->getFilename() => $path); `

Answer (score 1):

credit : https://stackoverflow.com/a/952324/1842842

This code

```
$fileData = convertDirectoryToArray( new DirectoryIterator( 'folder/' ) );

function convertDirectoryToArray( DirectoryIterator $dir )
{
  $data = array();
  foreach ( $dir as $node )
  {
    if ( $node->isDir() && !$node->isDot() )
    {
      $test = array();
      $test['text'] = $node->getFilename();
      $test['children'] = convertDirectoryToArray( new DirectoryIterator( $node->getPathname() ) );

      $data[] = $test;
    }
    else if ( $node->isFile() )
    {
      $test= array();
      $test['text'] = $node->getFilename();
      $test['icon'] = "jstree-file";
      $data[] = $test;
    }
  }
  return $data;
}

print_r(json_encode($fileData));
```

produces

```
[{"text":"Christmas.docx"},{"text":"test1","children":[{"text":"1.docx"}]},{"text":"test2","children":[{"text":"2.txt"},{"text":"New folder","children":[{"text":"4.txt"}]}]}]
```

Which is what i was looking for!